# Can I use a 220v engine to build up a RC car?

Tags: motor, electric-machine

sorry for the noob question, but I'd like to build myself a small RC car. I've found this motor in a blender, which runs at 220v.

Can I power it with a lower voltage? What should I use?

Thanks a lot, I'd appreciate some good help :)
[image: that's the motor]

Comment: c'mon, John, how can anyone answer this? What kind of motor? What kind of blender? Pics? Description? Part numbers? 
That said, small high speed appliance motors are often 'universal', and will run on DC. Just try it with a battery, see what happens.

Comment: @BobbiBennett - actually, a general answer would not depend too much on the previously missing information.  And small *consumer* appliances (in contrast to larger commercial versions) are almost always universal motors as induction motors are too bulky/expensive and brushless requires control electronics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motor you have found is probably AC and runs at a high voltage (although there is no harm in trying it out with a low DC voltage as mentioned in case it is not 220VAC driven).
Whilst in theory it is possible to use any motor if you drive it correctly, this is not the right type for an application such as this. The high voltage makes it needlessly dangerous, and would need to be created from a lower voltage DC source (i.e. a battery)
So rather than convert a low voltage DC source, you are better off using a low voltage DC motor. If you check on any RC hobby store site, you should see many suitable options, and the batteries to power them (plus servos, and other things you need for an RC car)

Here is one such [motor](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__23360__Turnigy_TrackStar_8_5T_Sensored_Brushless_Motor_3983KV.html) from [Hobby King](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__364__59__Electric_Motors-All_Car_Motors.html) which runs from 7.4V to 11.1V DC:

[image: Motor]

Answer (score 2):

Small kitchen appliances are often "universal" motors rather than induction motors, and will run on AC or DC. If you can see two carbon "brushes" running on a segmented copper ring (the commutator) then you have a universal motor. The picture below shows a small domestic (but not kitchen!) appliance motor.

[image: Universal motor]

It may not run at any significant speed on 12V DC however, or it may run but with too little torque to be useful. It would be theoretically feasible to rewind it for lower voltages (fewer turns of thicker wire) but that is not an easy operation!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a power or analog guy. I've seen step-up power sources. It is from National Instruments to power up their industrial computers. I think it has a lead-acid battery and can be stepped up to 220V.

You might take a look at some switching regulators which might do the job.

But you will be better off to buy a motor that runs on a battery directly. Power regulation is not 100% efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are real good that a 220V motor from a blender is going to be an induction motor, that only runs on AC.

There are OODLES of small DC motors available that are specifically designed for RC car applications.  Start with [Tower Hobbies](http://www.towerhobbies.com/): they're reputable.

Comment: Actually, an induction motor is unlikely in a small countertop appliance.